# How to make the umi project combine with the electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I use npx created a [umi](https://github.com/umijs/umi) project :

```
npx create-umi@latest
```

you see the directories of it:

[image]

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── src
├── test.js
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings.d.ts
└── yarn.lock

./src
└── pages
    ├── config-graph.tsx
    ├── index.less
    ├── index.tsx
    ├── react-edge
    │   ├── edge1.less
    │   ├── edge1.tsx
    │   ├── edge2.less
    │   └── edge2.tsx
    └── react-node
        ├── node1.less
        ├── node1.tsx
        ├── node2.less
        └── node2.tsx
```

now I want to create a electron app base on it,

and i created electron directory like below:

```
├── electron
        ├── index.html
    ├── main
    │   └── main.js
    └── renderer
        └── preload.js
```

but how can I make the umi react component mount on `electron/index.html`? I found umi don't use index.html.

So, how to make the umi project combine with the electron?